# error in hardhat basic example (deploy.ts)

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

deploy.ts

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + 60;

  const lockedAmount = ethers.parseEther("0.001");

  const lock = await ethers.deployContract("Lock", [unlockTime], {value: lockedAmount});

  await lock.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    `Lock with ${ethers.formatEther(
      lockedAmount
    )}ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.target}`
  );
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

error occured in this line

`const lock = await ethers.deployContract("Lock", [unlockTime], {value: lockedAmount});`

underlined part

`value`

error message

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(name: "Lock", args: any[], signerOrOptions?: Signer | FactoryOptions | undefined): Promise<Lock>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ value: bigint; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signer | FactoryOptions | undefined'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'Signer | FactoryOptions'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(name: string, args: any[], signerOrOptions?: Signer | FactoryOptions | undefined): Promise<Contract>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ value: bigint; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signer | FactoryOptions | undefined'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'Signer | FactoryOptions'.ts(2769)
```

plz help me
what is this error?

Comment: Are you sure `ethers` have a function `deployContract()`?

Answer (score 0):

The error cause is explained on this [hardhat issue](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/4118) and should work with the latest versions